# Converting nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I have variable called @prmclientcode which is nvarchar. The input to this variable can be a single client code or multiple client codes separated by comma. For e.g.

```
@prmclientcode='1'
or
@prmclientcode='1,2,3'.
```

I am comparing this variable to a client code column in of the tables. The data type of this column is numeric(6,0). I tried converting the variable data type like below

```
SNCA_CLIENT_CODE IN ('''+convert(numeric(6,0),@prmclientcode+''')) (The query is inside a dynamic sql).
```

But when I try executing this I get the error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Can anyone please help me here!

Thanks!

Comment: TRY THIS:

Declare var nvarchar(500)
SET  var = '1,2,3'

exec (N'select * from yortable where column in ('+ @var  +')

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the numeric(6,0) column to nvarchar data type. You can use below scrip to convert it to nvarchar, before processing:

```
 SNCA_CLIENT_CODE IN ('''+convert(cast( numeric(6,0) as nvarchar(max) ),@prmclientcode+'''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
(
  ProductID int
)

INSERT INTO @ProductTotals VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @ProductTotals VALUES(11)
INSERT INTO @ProductTotals VALUES(3)

DECLARE @prmclientcode VARCHAR(MAX)='1'


SELECT * FROM @ProductTotals

SELECT * FROM @ProductTotals WHERE  CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(ProductID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' , ',' + ISNULL(@prmclientcode,ProductID) + ',') > 0
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in order to separate your variable:

```
DECLARE 
    @T VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,3,23,342',
    @I int = 1

;WITH x(I, num) AS (
    SELECT 1, CHARINDEX(',',@T,@I)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT num+1,CHARINDEX(',',@T,num+1) 
    FROM x
    WHERE num+1<LEN(@T)
        AND num<>0
)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@T,I,CASE WHEN num=0 THEN LEN(@T)+1 ELSE num END -I)
FROM x
```

Answer (score -1):

Use can use either table function or dynamic sql query, both options will work.

Let me know if you need more help